# How can I automatically create a backup of a user?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, winapi

I was wondering if it was possible to programatically interact with [Windows Easy Transfer](http://enwp.org/Windows_Easy_Transfer) (migwiz.exe) or another tool in order to automatically create a backup of a user.

I looked everywhere but it seems like Microsoft hasn't published anything like that. I was wondering if any of you had an idea on how to start. I know I can start the program (migwiz.exe) but this doesn't help me a lot. Maybe there is a DLL that this program is using that I could use myself?

Comment: You could record what it does with ProcessExplorer and repeat the same actions. I doubt it's doing anything magic.

Comment: That's something interesting ! I'll look into that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [migration tool](http://www.infoworld.com/t/windows/11-tools-windows-7-migrations-484). Microsoft's [User State Migration Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_State_Migration_Tool) is one choice, and it's freeware.  Maybe it will suit your needs.  It's command-line-driven.

Why do you want to "create a backup of a user"?